# Laravel-4 Carbon throwing toString() error when formatting date

Tags: php, laravel-4, date-formatting

In my projects index view I am returning the database fields including when a project starts. However the date format in sql only allows the format `0000-00-00` and I want to view it in `d-m-Y`.

I want to use [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api-formatting) to achieve this as it seems like a versatile plugin to use. However I'm not sure how to get it to work, I've added it into my app.php file as so:

`'Carbon'          => 'Carbon/Carbon'`

And I'm trying to format it as so in my index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($projects as $project)
   <div class="one-third column">

    <ul class="data">
    <li><label>Project Name: </label>{{ $project->project_name }}</li>
    <li><label>Project Brief</label>{{ $project->project_brief }}</li>
    $format = 'Y-m-d';
    $brief = $project->brief;
    <label>Created: </label><li>{{ Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $brief) }}</li>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

However I get thrown the following error:

`Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception`

Not really sure where I'm going wrong as I've never used it before. Anyone have any experience with Carbon that can help me out??

Answer (score 5):

I thought I'd add my answer as well, just in case someone is still looking for another way to do this and stumbles across this SO.

The following is an example of using Carbon's `format()` function with Laravel.  In my case, I'm formatting the created_at Timestamp field created in one of my migrations.

```
{{$project->created_at->format('m/d/Y')}}
```

You can use date formats as provided on PHP.net:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I like this one! its Laravel stye, simple and fast! thanks

Do You have any idea how to deal with month names in german? Is there any Laravel-Way-To-Do??

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to write PHP code inside your Blade file. That won't work, at least not the way it is now. I assume `$project` is a model, am I right? If so, and if `brief` is defined as `DATE` on the database, Laravel automatically converts it to a Carbon instance. Then, what you probably want is this:

```
{{ $project->brief->toDateString() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/app.php`:

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Berlin',
```

In your model:

```
// Any Kind of Eloquent Model
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

   public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value) { //created_at field in DB
       setlocale(LC_ALL, 'German');
       return $carbonDate = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value)->formatLocalized('%A %d. %B %Y');
   }
```

Result in view: 
`{{ $userData->created_at }}`

"Mittwoch 29. Januar 2014"

**Update**
You can then translate your Date formats in the language files `lang/en` and use them like

```
..formatLocalized(trans('formats.long-date'))
```